# Job not dispatching to jobs table Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, driver, jobs

I'm dispatching a Job, which should go to jobs table, according to my .env config (`QUEUE_DRIVER=database`)

But what happens is that nothing appears in jobs table and the job doesnt even run on sync mode, for example. I've watched `queue:listen`, Laravel log file, **failed_jobs** table is empty as well. Please help me, my job is **gone**

**OBS:** I'm running `artisan config:clear` after changing .env file and then i restart PHP FPM service

One thing i noticed is that when I turn QUEUE_DRIVER to `sync`, it runs all jobs I've dispatched even they didnt go to jobs table

Am I loosing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in lumen 8.x today.
I was queuing using `dispatch(new ExampleJob);` so after spending some good time googling with no success, I decided to replaced `dispatch(new ExampleJob);` with `Queue::push(new ExampleJob);`.
My vscode code editor threw unknown class error so I added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;` at the top of the class then jobs started queuing fine.
For more details refer to [Dispatching Jobs section](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues). I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This issue started happening for me last week on Laravel 10.x. I had tried both redis and database queue drivers but the job would never show up in the queue no matter what I tried. But changing from `ExampleJob::dispatch()` to  `Queue::push(new ExampleJob)` did the trick. No clue why yet, but I'll dig into the distinct code paths when I have a chance and follow up here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use queues with the database driver and your project handles more than one database connection,
Maybe your queue table is not in the default connection and in that case you should make sure to set the database connection configuration correctly in the queue connection configuration.

In my case, when adding the job to the queue, the request reached its maximum execution time.

After reviewing the queue configurations several times, I noticed that I had the "database connection" that uses the "queue connection" set incorrectly.

In my .env:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

In config/queue:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),

'connections' => [

         'sync' => [
             'driver' => 'sync',
         ],

         'database' => [
             'driver' => 'database',
             'connection' => 'sync', //<-- "sync" is my database connection name, it could also be "mysql" or "my_own_custom_database_connection", enter your DB connection that has your jobs table
             'table' => 'jobs',
             'queue' => 'default',
             'retry_after' => 90,
             'after_commit' => false,
         ],
```

** notice the comment in the key connections.database.connection, it says:

> "sync" is my database connection name (but it is not the default of
> the project), it could also be "mysql" or
> "my_own_custom_database_connection", enter your DB connection that has
> your jobs table.

I know that by having the connection incorrectly specified, the request never ends, and reaches max_execution_time

Answer (score -1):

When you set QUEUE_DRIVER to sync, dispatched jobs will be immediately run and not be inserted in the jobs table.
So you should set it to 'database' to get the desired action.